# Qt: Does QStandardItem take ownership of pointer through QVariant?

Tags: c++, qt

When I do:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyType*);

MyType* myData = new MyType;

QStandardItem* stdItem = new QStandardItem;

QVariant var;
var.setValue(myData);

stdItem->setData(var);
```

Does `stdItem` take ownership of `myData`? Or how do I need to use `QStandardItem` and `QVariant` in Qt in order to make sure that the user-defined type of data a `QVariant` holds is deleted when `QStandardItem` is removed from a `QTreeView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not take ownership.

The variant is copied into the standard item, it doesn't know that the variant itself contains a pointer.

The variant also copies the pointer, it doesn't take ownership either.

One way to solve this is to not store a raw pointer inside the variant, but using a smart pointer instead
E.g. `std::shared_ptr` if your compiler is recent enough for C++11 or `QSharedPointer` if it is not.

Another options it to not use a `QStandardItemModel` but a custom model that operates on your data, thus also controlling how you want to handle storage and ownership.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I would like to ask something though. If I want to make sure that the data QStandardItem carries is deleted upon the item's deletion, isn't shared pointer a wrong choice since it may leave references "outside" even after the item is deleted; thus, leading to the data still being "alive" in memory? I actually have tried doing this with unique pointer but I found it very difficult to work with unique pointers. I would like to hear your opinion on this. Also, having a custom item model is a very good idea, thank you.

Comment: This won't be a problem unless you kept a shared pointer copy around elsewere. I.e. if you create the shared pointer of your object on the stack, then put it in the variant, then the one on the stack will be gone when the function's scope ends and the one in the variant is the only remaining.
So when the item is deleted, its variant data is deleted, which deletes the last shared pointer to your object and thus deletes the object

Comment: Thank you again. I see your point and that's again a very good idea. However I have a question about your approach. My `QStandardItem`s are owned by my `QTreeView`, which is always alive for the entirety of run time. And when I call `removeRow()` on that item, it is removed from the view; however, not deleted, since `QTreeView` is still alive. If I follow your approach, should I explicity call `delete` on `QStandardItem`s? I actually tried this, it throws an exception though.

Comment: `removeRow()` calls `removeRows()` and that deletes the items: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/itemmodels/qstandarditemmodel.cpp.html#_ZN13QStandardItem10removeRowsEii

Comment: I have taken a look at the implementation of `removeRow()` and `removeRows()`. I think the best for my case will be having a custom item inheriting from `QStandardItem`, which either explicitly `delete`s its data in its destructor; or better yet, contains a shared pointer or maybe unique pointer to its data so I don't need to do much in its destructor, as you have suggested. Thank you.